# when I enter values in my table the primary key is allowed as null

Tags: phpmyadmin, null

I use phpmyadmin to create a database however when I enter values in my table the primary key is allowed to be null although it is not created that way. Why is this happening? please see create table statement from phpmyadmin below:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscriber` (  
    `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    `phone_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,  
    `node_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
    `node_number` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `shelf` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `card` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `port` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `ONT` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `registration_id` int(5) NOT NULL,  
    `comment` text NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`phone_number`) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key is `text`

A primary key is a column or a set of columns that uniquely identifies each row in the table. You must follow the rules below when you define a primary key for a table:

A primary key must contain unique values.

If the primary key consists of multiple columns, the combination of values in these columns must be unique.

A primary key column cannot contain NULL values. It means that you have to declare the primary key column with the NOT NULL  attribute.

If you don’t, MySQL will force the primary key column as NOT NULL  implicitly.
A table has only one primary key.

Because MySQL works faster with integers, the data type of the primary key column should be the integer e.g., INT, BIGINT.You can choose a smaller integer type: TINYINT, SMALLINT, etc.

Comment: I know that information I studied database design. My problem is when I fill out the information in phpmyadmin or the web form without entering the phone number the record is saved. The phone number is the primary key therefore it Should not save the record. I want to know why this is happening?